# gtk actions: where is the list for keyboard keys (syntax) for accelerators?

Tags: gtk

I wanted to assign `/` as gtk action accelerator, I tried `"/"` At runtime I've got:

```
(app_name:some_id): Gtk-WARNING **: time_stamp_like: Unable to parse accelerator '/' for action 'some-action'
```

Accelerators that work are coded as e.g. `"<alt>Return"`, `"m"`, `"Left"`. Web search did not help to find syntax for keys. At https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/ , https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/ search for e.g. `<alt>` returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

For "/" it's "slash".

https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk4/stable/gtk4-Keyboard-Accelerators.html

> Parses a string representing an accelerator. The format looks like
> “a” or “F1”.
>
> The parser is fairly liberal and allows lower or upper case, and also
> abbreviations such as “” and “”. Key names are parsed using
> gdk_keyval_from_name(). For character keys the name is not the symbol,
> but the lowercase name, e.g. one would use “minus” instead of
> “-”.

https://developer-old.gnome.org/gdk4/stable/gdk4-Keyboard-Handling.html

> gdk_keyval_from_name ()
>
> The names are the same as those in the
> gdk/gdkkeysyms.h header file but without the leading “GDK_KEY_”.

I've found `gdkkeysyms.h` in `/usr/include/...`.